# is possible to theme chrome with chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

It is possible to programmatically theme, via javascript in an extension, the chrome's gui?

I want  change  background color of particular tab [image]  with another color

Comment: Do you mean change the background of particular tab and not others ? Be more precise.

Comment: I'm not expert but I don't think this kind of things are possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Chrome does not provide any APIs to style its GUI programmatically - so you can't make a tab be of a different color depending on a condition.